# Unable to reference filtered array in ngRepeat - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `ngRepeat` directive that is filtered as:

```
<li ng-repeat='item in items | filter:searchTerm as filteredItems'>{{item.name}}</li>
```

I am tring to access the `filteredItems` in my controller like `$scope.filteredItems` but I'm getting an undefined. How should I solve this?

I have nested controllers. Is the problem with `$scope`?

My controllers are something like this in my view:

```
<div ng-controller='MainController'>
 <div ng-controller='FilterController'>
  <li ng-repeat='item in items | filter:searchTerm as filteredItems'>{{item.name}}</li>
 </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to access `$scope.filteredItems` in `FilterController`.

Comment: Will you please share more code ?

Comment: Which part would you need?

Comment: Nested controllers ??

Comment: you can try `<li ng-repeat='item in (filteredItems = items | filter:searchTerm)'>{{item.name}}</li>`, but not sure that this works, also this code can add `filteredItems` not in main scope, but in ngRepeat own scope

Comment: @Grundy Exactly. That's why we need to see more code to answer proper.

Comment: I have added more code.
@Grundy I actually tried that, but it doesn't seem to work!

Comment: @Vineet, i sure OP mean main controller :-)

Comment: @Grundy How do I access `filteredItems` in it's scope? I'm a beginner.

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed, can you provide jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: Please give me sometime so I can make one.

Comment: @FaizuddinMohammed, sure, anyway you can filter in controller and in view just use filtered array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82852/discussion-between-grundy-and-faizuddin-mohammed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use assigning in `ng-repeat` expression like `ng-repeat='item in filteredItems = (items | filter:searchTerm)'`
**NOTE:** in comment was wrong variant, because assigning more priority than pipe.

```js
var appModule = angular.module('app', []);
appModule.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
    //some functions and variables here
    $scope.items = [
        {name:'1234'},
        {name:'2341'},
        {name:'3412'},
        {name:'4123'},
        {name:'4321'}
    ];
});
appModule.controller('FilterController', function ($scope) {
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='MainController'>
    <div ng-controller='FilterController'>
        <!-- FilterController has many filters that are not related -->
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchTerm" />
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat='item in filteredItems = (items | filter:searchTerm)'>{{item.name}}</li>
        </ul>
        {{filteredItems}}
    </div>
</div>
```

but seems that better filter in controller:

```js
var appModule = angular.module('app', []);
appModule.controller('MainController', function ($scope) {
    //some functions and variables here
    $scope.items = [
        {name:'1234'},
        {name:'2341'},
        {name:'3412'},
        {name:'4123'},
        {name:'4321'}
    ];
});
appModule.controller('FilterController', function ($scope,$filter) {
    var filter = $filter('filter');
    $scope.filter = function(){
      $scope.filteredItems = filter($scope.items, $scope.searchTerm);
    }
    $scope.filter();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='MainController'>
    <div ng-controller='FilterController'>
        <!-- FilterController has many filters that are not related -->
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchTerm" ng-change="filter()" />
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat='item in filteredItems'>{{item.name}}</li>
        </ul>
        {{filteredItems}}
    </div>
</div>
```